# SVG image not rendering correctly in some screens

Tags: svg, renderer, hardware-acceleration, amd-processor, image-rendering

We are seeing a weird issue in rendering an SVG image in Chrome in Acer machine with AMD processor. We have an SVG image and it shows up properly in most of the laptop screens.

In Acer (with AMD processor), the SVG file is rendered with green patches on top of the image as attached.

Has anyone faced this kind of issue? Any pointers or solutions are highly appreciated.[image: render]

Comment: You could try [disabling acceleration](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=chrome+graphics+acceleration) and maybe [report a chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) if there isn't one already filed.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson. This image shows properly when we disable hardware acceleration. Could it be the way how SVG is built? I will also raise a bug in Chromium